# Limit of a sequence of roots

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $L$ be a real number and $\rho \in (0, 1)$. Define the following sequence,
$a_0 = 0$,
$a_1 = L^\rho$, 
$a_i = (L + a_{i-1})^{\rho}$. 
Is $\lim\limits_{i \rightarrow \infty} a_i= \infty$ for all values of $L >1$ and $\rho \in (0, 1)$? If yes, how to prove it?

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is intended for questions about limit theorems in probability theory and not for questions about determining limits of sequences or functions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Draw a graph!

The function $u:a\mapsto(L+a)^\rho$ is increasing (this is where one uses that $\rho\gt0$), such that $u(a)\gt a$ for every $a$ in $[0,a^*)$ and $u(a)\lt a$ for every $a$ in $(a^*,+\infty)$ (this is where one uses that $\rho\lt1$), for some $a^*\gt0$ (and even $a^*\gt1$) which is uniquely defined by the identity
$$
a^*=u(a^*).
$$
Thus, for every starting point $a_0$ in $[0,a^*)$ (such as $a_0=0$), the sequence defined by $a_n=u(a_{n-1})$ for every $n\geqslant1$ is increasing and converges to $a^*$.

Likewise,  for every starting point $a_0$ in $(a^*,+\infty)$, the sequence defined by $a_n=u(a_{n-1})$ for every $n\geqslant1$ is decreasing and converges to $a^*$.